# Получить данные с одной таблицы по id из другой

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго дня.

Задача выглядит так.
Есть таблица вида. "user"

```
id | author | text1_id | text2_id | text3_id
1  | alex   |    1     |    2     |    1
```

И есть вторая таблица. "info"

```
id | text1 | text2 | text3
1  |   A1  |  A2   |  A3
2  |   B1  |  B2   |  B3
```

Хочу получить на выходе таблицу вида

```
id | author | text1 | text2 | text3
1  | alex   |  A1   |  B2   |  A3
```

Пробовал через `JOIN`, но он мне не выдает раздельные значения для каждого текста.

Или лучше вообще избежать `JOIN'ов` и внутри делать простые 3 запроса на получения нужного текста по `id`?

Comment: Что то у вас с структурой БД совсем не так. В таблице не должно быть колонок text1_id, text2_id и т.п. Так же как и нескольких текстов в info. любые множественные значения должны быть вынесены в отдельную таблицу, в виде отдельных записей.

Comment: А так как у вас сейчас вам надо сделать 3 join с таблицей info по разным полям и из каждой из низ взять один из текстов

Comment: `select a.*, i1.text1, i2.text2 from user a join info i1 on i1.id=a.text1_id join join info i2 on i2.id=a.text2_id ...`

Comment: по структуре так дано в задании, да и поля эти заполняются через 1 форму. Последний вариант подошел. Я совсем забыл что нужно каждый JOIN именовать по разному. Спасибо.